# mockito UnfinishedStubbingException in stead of wanted Exception

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to mock an service with bad clientresponses for testing.
I still get an UnfinishedStubbingException in min eclass in stead of an ClientResponseFailure and I can't see where I did wrong.
I tried also :

```
 Mockito.when(hrServiceBad.verifyIdentity("412", "aaa", "aaa")).thenThrow(clientResponseFailure);
```

but gives the same result.

Mine code :

```
@Autowired
private CheckUserServiceImpl checkUserService;
private HrService hrServiceBad;
private ClientResponseFailure clientResponseFailure;
private ClientResponseImpl response = new ClientResponseImpl();

@Before
public void init() {
    hrServiceBad = Mockito.mock(HrService.class);
    checkUserService.setHrService(hrServiceBad);
    clientResponseFailure = new ClientResponseFailure(response);
}

@Test(expected = EsbVerificationError.class)
public void testUserValidInEsbWith412Fault() throws EsbOffLineException, EsbVerificationError {
    // precondition failed
    response.setStatus(412);
    Mockito.doThrow(clientResponseFailure).when(hrServiceBad.verifyIdentity("412", "aaa", "aaa"));
    checkUserService.verifyUserInEsb("412", "aaa", "aaa");
}

@Test(expected = EsbOffLineException.class)
public void testUserValidInEsbWith503Fault() throws EsbOffLineException, EsbVerificationError {
    // service unavailable
    response.setStatus(503);
    Mockito.when(hrServiceBad.verifyIdentity("503", "aaa", "aaa"))
            .thenThrow(clientResponseFailure);

    checkUserService.verifyUserInEsb("503", "aaa", "aaa");
}

@Test(expected = EsbOffLineException.class)
public void testUserValidInEsbWith404Fault() throws EsbOffLineException, EsbVerificationError {
    // page not found
    response.setStatus(404);
    Mockito.when(hrServiceBad.verifyIdentity("404", "aaa", "aaa"))
            .thenThrow(clientResponseFailure);

    checkUserService.verifyUserInEsb("404", "aaa", "aaa");
}

@Test(expected = EsbOffLineException.class)
public void testUserValidInEsbWith403Fault() throws EsbOffLineException, EsbVerificationError {
    // page forbidden
    response.setStatus(403);
    Mockito.when(hrServiceBad.verifyIdentity("403", "aaa", "aaa"))
            .thenThrow(clientResponseFailure);
    checkUserService.verifyUserInEsb("403", "aaa", "aaa");
}

@Test(expected = EsbOffLineException.class)
public void testUserValidInEsbWith522Fault() throws EsbOffLineException, EsbVerificationError {
    // connection timeout
    response.setStatus(522);
    Mockito.when(hrServiceBad.verifyIdentity("522", "aaa", "aaa"))
            .thenThrow(clientResponseFailure);
    checkUserService.verifyUserInEsb("522", "aaa", "aaa");
}
```

}

the checkUserServiceImpl :

```
 @Override
public void verifyUserInEsb(final String nationalNumber, final String serviceNumber,
        final String bafuser) throws EsbOffLineException, EsbVerificationError {
    String cleanedNationalNumber = BulletinUserManager.keepDigitsOnly(nationalNumber);
    try {
        Identity identity = this.hrService.verifyIdentity(cleanedNationalNumber, serviceNumber, bafuser);
        if (identity != null) {
            //more code here but not relevant.
            return;
        }
    } catch (ClientResponseFailure e) {
        logger.info(e.getResponse().getStatus());
        if (PRECONDITION_FAILED == e.getResponse().getStatus()) {
            throw new EsbVerificationError("Hr check failed");
        }
    }        
    throw new EsbOffLineException();
}
```

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There where multiple faults.
First one was indeed like Stefan Birkner said.

Second :

```
@Autowired
private CheckUserServiceImpl checkUserService;
private HrService hrServiceBad;
private ClientResponseFailure clientResponseFailure;
private ClientResponseImpl response = new ClientResponseImpl();

@Before
public void init() {
    hrServiceBad = Mockito.mock(HrService.class);
    checkUserService.setHrService(hrServiceBad);
}

@Test(expected = EsbVerificationError.class)
public void testUserValidInEsbWith412Fault() throws EsbOffLineException, EsbVerificationError {
    // precondition failed
    response.setStatus(412);
    clientResponseFailure = new ClientResponseFailure(response); // add this.
    Mockito.doThrow(clientResponseFailure).when(hrServiceBad).verifyIdentity("412", "aaa", "aaa");
    checkUserService.setHrService(hrServiceBad);
    checkUserService.verifyUserInEsb("412", "aaa", "aaa");
}
```

What was wrong? after a little search I saw that the response.getStatus was giving code 0.
With the init directly in each test and set first the errorcode in the response before adding the response to the ClientResponseFailure fixed the whole thing.

When you do this :

```
clientResponseFailure = new ClientResponseFailure(response);
response.setStatus(412);
```

the test fails.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Mockito.doThrow wrong.

Your code:

```
Mockito.doThrow(clientResponseFailure).when(hrServiceBad.verifyIdentity("412", "aaa", "aaa"));
```

But the `when` method needs only your mock as a single parameter:

```
Mockito.doThrow(clientResponseFailure).when(hrServiceBad).verifyIdentity("412", "aaa", "aaa");
```

Comment: Now I'm getting always the EsbOfflineException, so no Exception is thrown in HrService.